# What is the highest upper limit on resistance of superconducting phase?

Tags: experimental-physics, superconductivity

What is the highest precision achieved in the measure of the upper limit of the resistance of the superconducting phase (for any superconductor)?

Comment: Are you asking about instrument limitations or whether a superconductor is actually a superconductor?

Comment: The most accurate way (As far as I know) of measuring the resistance of a superconductor is in measuring the decay time of a persistent current in a superconducting ring (which is supposed to be infinite, but experimentally you cannot measure it for an infine time). 
I remember from some classes I had a couple years ago that the most precise measurement was done by letting a persistent current flow for something like an year, but I cannot find any reference, and the error they obtained.
That's what I'm asking.

Comment: Ah okay, perhaps edit your question to clearly state that so that the reader knows precisely to what you refer.